# Use Regex.Replace to format TimeSpan Components

Tags: c#, regex, converters, timespan

I'm using .net 3.5 and I would like to find out if there is a way to use Regex.Replace to format TimeSpan components for user provided formats. Ideally the user could send several types of desired formats as arguments - e.g. HH:mm, hh:mm, dd:hh:mm, mm:ss and so on. The replace function would interrogate the user format and return the TimeSpan value in the desired format.

I've done a bit of digging and have come up with the below. It's not a solution, but will give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
  // Sample Replace Pattern for TimeSpan
            string pattern = @"(?<dd>\d{2}).(?<hh>\d{2}).(?<mm>\d{2})";
            string replaceStr = @"{dd:hh:mm}";
            var myRegEx = new Regex(pattern);
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(3, 10,3, 22);
            string dateResult = myRegEx.Replace(ts.ToString(), replaceStr);
```

Thanks - Glenn

Comment: You can't differentiate hh:mm from mm:ss, example: 10:45

Comment: Casimir - The goal is to pass any format desired. If the user want's mm:ss or MM:ss, it should be able to resolve. Glenn

Answer (score 2):

You can use ToString method of TimeSpan As below , You don't need regex for this if I understood correctly

```
 string dateResult = ts.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm");
```

if you have multiple formats then like below

```
HH:mm, hh:mm, dd:hh:mm, mm:ss
```

then replace input `:` with `\:` and apend `@` to the begin

You can now use this format string to call ToString method of TimeSpan

Comment: Thanks Damith - Unfortunately I am using .Net 3.5 which does not include the rather nice extension methods. Glenn

Comment: Its there but only returns the raw string. Look closely. In the documentation they have a custom method to format the string to something that looks like a date time format. In 4 or 4.5 you can pass the desired format and return the span in the that format. Not so in 3.5 Glenn